# solution of GBM doubt

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

giving the dynamics of a GBM: $dX_t=\alpha X_tdt+\sigma X_tdW_t$, I know that the solution $X_t=X_0 e^{(\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t+\sigma W_t}$ is given by ito applied to $\ln(X_t)$. My question is: Where is the mistake if I compute the solution in this other way:

$\frac{dX_t}{X_t}=\alpha dt +\sigma dW_t$

$\int_0^t\frac{dX_t}{X_t}=\int_0^t\alpha dt +\int_0^t\sigma dW_t$

$[\ln(X_t)]_0^t=\alpha t+\sigma W_t$

$\ln(\frac{X_t}{X_0})=\alpha t+\sigma W_t$

$X_t=X_0 e^{\alpha t+\sigma W_t}$

Comment: The claim would be correct if you just consider deterministic functions. The problem is that the fundamental theorem of calculus does not apply. Even though your process is continuous, it is nowhere differentiable. Thus, you can not expect to apply the same tools of the Leibniz calculus to these kinds of problems. By these problems is where Itôs magic appears. It enables you to perform calculus on processes.

Answer (score 1):

For an Ito integral

$$\int_0^t \frac{dX_t}{X_t} \neq [\ln(X_t)]_0^t.$$

You need to apply Ito's lemma here.

Comment: It is not equal because $dX_t$ is stochastic, right?

Comment: Yes you are interpreting it as a Riemann integral, which is incorrect. These standard rules do not directly apply to stochastic integrals.

Comment: perfect, thanks

Comment: In the case I would compute only $\int_0^t dX_t$, is $\int_0^t dX_t=X_t-X_0$ correct?

Comment: @Fabio yes that is correct.